# How to get Generic Parameter Type of class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to get the type of Generic Parameter for some class, such as:

```
class ClassA<T> {
    value!: T;

    getParameterType()  {
        return <type of T>;
    }
}
```

the `getParameterType` method return the Class Type of T, and how to do it ? or has other methods?

Comment: What do you mean by "Class Type of T"? What should it return for `ClassA<string>` for example?

Comment: You can't get return the type T in a function because thats javscript code and types don't exist in JS. I think what you want is to extract the generic type T from classA. you can do something like that with the infer keyword and can then be used to generate new types, but you can't return a type since a type is not a value its the same as saying 'return string'

Comment: Give me second to work out the answer

Answer (score 5):

You can't return a type in Typescript, since a type is not a value. Typescript compiles to Javascript so types don't exist there. The error you get when I compile your code(when I concatenate the 'type' and 'of' into `typeof`) says:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

and that's completly correct, you can only return values and use these values to perform operations on. You can't return a type. This is the same thing as writing the following function:

```
function wrong() {
    return string // You can return 'hello world'
}
```

You can't say `return string`

Also look what happens with your typescript code when you compile it:

`let x: string = 'hello world'` becomes in Javascript `let x = 'hello world'` 
The types are gone!

## Solution

What you are looking for is a type to extract the generic parameter `T` from the `ClassA`, typescript has keyword `infer` wich allows you get the to get the type parameters of any type.

`type getType<T> = T extends ClassA<infer U> ? U : never`

and use it like this:

`type Test = getType<ClassA<string>>` the type of Test is string

### NOTE:

Pay attention to to difference in types and values, they are not the same things and are treated completely different.

Comment: Thank you very much! I Got it.

Comment: Your welcome, the type `getType` will return a never when the generic type parameter is not of type `ClassA`